# php ldap bind can't contact server

Tags: php, ldap

I'm using Centos 7, and I'm having "Can't contact LDAP server" error when using php ldap_bind() function. I've tried ldapsearch and it connected successfully. I'm not sure how to solve the issue. Any help is welcome.

```
$ldaphost = "HOST";
$ldapport = PORT;

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport);

if ($ldapconn) {
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);
    if (!$ldapbind) {
        echo ldap_error($ldapconn);
    }
    else {
        echo "it finally workd";
    }
}

ldap_close($ldapconn);
```

And my command line ldapsearch is
`ldapsearch -h HOST -p PORT`

Comment: Are you using SSL when connecting to the LDAP server?

Comment: Typically LDAPS runs on port 636 and LDAP runs on port 389. If you are using LDAPS, the connect command looks like:

    ldap_connect("ldaps://<servername>", 636);

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments. No, I'm not using SSL. @Sebastien The error was `Can't contact LDAP server` when I run the php code. I'm using the same port, 389, and the same host ip for both the php and the ldapsearch command.

Comment: @MrTux Forgot to add your username to my last comment. But no, I'm not using SSL.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right host string? something like `ldap://something.exemple.com`?

Comment: @Sebastien I think so because using any ldap client, the host works. And I'm just using an IP address. So for host, I put "XX-XX-XX-XX" and port is "389". Thanks for continuing to help me.

Comment: So something like `ldap://192.168.0.1:389`? or just `192.168.0.1:389`?

Comment: I am not sure but I think the `ldap://` is important.

Comment: @Sebastien I tried it with "ldap://..." and got the same error: Can't contact LDAP Server. I thought it might be something to do with the php ldap install but phpinfo() shows ldap is enabled.

Comment: I guess the `if($ldapconn)` works, so the binding is probably your problem. If I am not mistaken there is two way to bind to the server 1:with a username and password 2: anonymously. To bind anonymously you have to activate an option but I am not sure what its name. else you might want to try and connect with a username and password just to see if this is the problem.